# Performance of dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, rtti, dynamic-cast

I previous asked a question [Why is dynamic_cast evil or not ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18439380/1145750) The answers made me to write some code about performance of `dynamic_cast` as follows.And I compiled and tested, the time consumed by `dynamic_cast` is slightly bigger than that without `dynamic_cast`.I didn't see the evidence of `dynamic_cast` is time consuming.Did I write the right code ?

The code is :

```
class Animal
{
public:
    virtual ~Animal(){};
};

class Cat : public Animal
{
public:
    std::string param1;
    std::string param2;
    std::string param3;
    std::string param4;
    std::string param5;
    int param6;
    int param7;
};

bool _process(Cat* cat)
{
    cat->param1 = "abcde";
    cat->param2 = "abcde";
    cat->param3 = "abcde";
    cat->param4 = "abcde";
    cat->param5 = "abcde";
    cat->param6 = 1;
    cat->param7 = 2;
    return true;
}

bool process(Animal *ptr)
{
    Cat *cat = dynamic_cast<Cat*>(ptr);
    if (cat == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    } 
    _process(cat);
    return true;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    /*
    argv[1] : object num
    */

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: invalid argc " << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    int obj_num = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (obj_num <= 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: object num" << std::endl;
    }

    int c = 0;
    for (; c < obj_num; c++)
    {
        Cat cat;
        #ifdef _USE_CAST
        if (!process(&cat))
        {
            std::cout << "Error: failed to process " << std::endl;
            return -3;
        }
        #else
        if (!_process(&cat))
        {
            std::cout << "Error: failed to process " << std::endl;
            return -3;
        }

        #endif
    }

    return 0;
}
```

compile it using:

```
g++ -D_USE_CAST -o dynamic_cast_test  dynamic_cast_benchmark.c
g++ -o dynamic_cast_no_test dynamic_cast_benchmark.c
```

execute them using num, which is 1,10,100 ...:

```
$time ./dynamic_cast_test num
$time ./dynamic_cast_no_test num
```

The result:

```
                 dynamic_cast               non_dynamic_cast
num  10,000   
                real    0m0.010s            real    0m0.008s
                user    0m0.006s            user    0m0.006s
                sys     0m0.001s            sys     0m0.001s

     100,000 
                real    0m0.059s            real    0m0.056s
                user    0m0.054s            user    0m0.054s
                sys     0m0.001s            sys     0m0.001s

     1,000,000
                real    0m0.523s            real    0m0.519s
                user    0m0.517s            user    0m0.511s
                sys     0m0.001s            sys     0m0.004s

     10,000,000
                real    0m6.050s            real    0m5.126s
                user    0m5.641s            user    0m4.986s
                sys     0m0.036s            sys     0m0.019s

     100,000,000
                real    0m52.962s           real    0m51.178s
                user    0m51.697s           user    0m50.226s
                sys     0m0.173s            sys     0m0.092s
```

hardware & os:

```
OS:Linux
CPU:Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5607  @ 2.27GHz  (4 cores)
```

Comment: For starters you're not compiling with optimizations. Add the `-O3` compiler flags.

Comment: dynamic_cast is usually discouraged because it indicates bad design rather than because it's "slow" (which is a relative thing)

Comment: What if you try it with multiple virtual inheritance?

Comment: You should try benchmarking with a deeper inheritance tree ( maybe some multiple inheritance also ). You'll then see significant differences

Comment: Here's some benchmarks: http://tinodidriksen.com/2010/04/14/cpp-dynamic-cast-performance/
Also be aware the modern compilers can sometimes optimize dynamic_casts out.

Comment: @Nicolas IMHO this is the best answer, yet.

Answer (score 1):

You did write the right code, althought I would not have hard-coded the type to be a Cat. You can, just to play on the safe side, use the command line argument to decide wether to build a cat or a, say, dog (which you should implement also). Try disabling optimization also, in order to see if it's playing a significant role.

Finally, a word of caution is in order. Profiling is not as simple as taking a measurement on your computer, so you must be aware that what you are doing only takes you so far. It does give you an idea, don't think you are getting any everything-encompassing answer though.

Answer (score -1):

I will reformulate my post.

Your code is correct, and it compiles well.

Since virtual methods and dynamic_cast operator are related issues, check this information from wiki, hope it will be useful.

wiki:

> A virtual call requires at least an extra indexed dereference, and
>   sometimes a "fixup" addition, compared to a non-virtual call, which is
>   simply a jump to a compiled-in pointer. Therefore, calling virtual
>   functions is inherently slower than calling non-virtual functions. An
>   experiment done in 1996 indicates that approximately 6–13% of
>   execution time is spent simply dispatching to the correct function,
>   though the overhead can be as high as 50%.[4] The cost of virtual
>   functions may not be so high on modern CPU architectures due to much
>   larger caches and better branch prediction.
>
> Furthermore, in environments where JIT compilation is not in use,
>   virtual function calls usually cannot be inlined. While a compiler
>   could replace the lookup and indirect call with, for instance, a
>   conditional execution of each inlined body, such optimizations are not
>   common.
>
> To avoid this overhead, compilers usually avoid using vtables whenever
>   the call can be resolved at compile time.
>
> Thus, the call to f1 above may not require a vtable lookup because the
>   compiler may be able to tell that d can only hold a D at this point,
>   and D does not override f1. Or the compiler (or optimizer) may be able
>   to detect that there are no subclasses of B1 anywhere in the program
>   that override f1. The call to B1::f1 or B2::f2 will probably not
>   require a vtable lookup because the implementation is specified
>   explicitly (although it does still require the 'this'-pointer fixup).

Also, as you probably know, when you declare a virtual method in your class, depends on realization but almost always, your compiler will implicitly add virtual method table as new memeber to your class, thus each instance of this class will occupy more memory space, try sizeof on class with vm and without it.

Comment: The question is not concerned with the cost of calling virtual functions.

Comment: @Stefano Falasca, I think it does, because, dynamic_cast and virtual methods are relative, are not they?

Comment: I won't say they are not related, since this would be difficult to substantiate. Nonetheless, consider that dynamic_cast needs RTTI to be enabled (well, not disabled), while you can indeed use virtual dispatching if RTTI is disabled.

Comment: I'm inclined to give this answer a +1 just so that it doesn't have the ugly minus sign anymore. It is useful information at least and I see that virtual functions and dynamic_cast are related (somehow). It may be my fault, sorry, but still I cannot see how this answers even a part of the question.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi, well, idk for sure how dynamic_cast operator works in depth, do you know? I would presume, dynamic_cast (when "RTTI is turned off" of course) lookups via vtable pointer anyway, so wiki says vtable lookup do costs, but on modern machines it is not so significant. That is why I believe tests made by author confused him a little bit, ("everybody says dynamic_cast operator is an evil, for christ sake, but my test shows it is ok!"). Mb I am wrong.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi, mb I should read twice the question.) IMHO when I think about dynamic_cast operator about its' evil, first of all I think about vtable pointer problems: size of instance and time cost during vtable lookup.